# TProcessInfo - Get fullpath of processes

Tags: delphi, process, delphi-xe2

I am using this non visual open source component called [TProcessInfo](http://vcldeveloper.com/products/products-components/process-info/) to get a list of processes, the ProcessID and the full path which I put into a ListView.

The code I am using to do this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  Process: TProcessItem;
begin
  for i := 0 to ProcessInfo1.RunningProcesses.Count -1 do
  begin
    Process := ProcessInfo1.RunningProcesses[i];
    with lv.Items.Add do
    begin
      Caption := Process.ExeFile;
      SubItems.Add(IntToStr(Process.ProcessID));
      SubItems.Add(Process.FullPath);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The code will always break on the last line: `SubItems.Add(Process.FullPath);` and I receive an Error Message:

System Error. Code: 87
The Parameter is incorrect.

The code that gets the FullPath in the Component is:

```
function TProcessItem.GetFullPath: TFileName;
var
  hProcess: THandle;
begin
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ,False,FProcessID);
  if hProcess <> 0 then
  begin
    try
      SetLength(Result,MAX_PATH);
      FillChar(Result[1],Length(Result) * SizeOf(Char), 0);
      if GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess,0,PChar(Result),Length(Result)) > 0 then
        Result := Trim(Result)
      else
       RaiseLastOSError;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hProcess)
    end;
  end
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

If like the Error states - the parameter is incorrect, then how can I change this?

** The component uses PsAPI and I am using Delphi XE2 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 also happens on Windows XP Pro x86

Comment: Which of the API calls fails? OpenProcess or GetModuleFileNameEx?

Comment: I have tried to set a breakpoint on OpenProcess and GetModuleFileNameEx but it always breaks on my line SubItems.Add(Process.FullPath);

Comment: Try harder to debug that code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I have removed the RaiseLastOSError calls and the Full Path of the processes I have access to are now added. I think I have no other option but to make this an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I think you should accept Slava's answer. It is accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because "System Idle Process" has PID = 0 and `OpenProcess` fails with such a ProcessID value. Patch the library to avoid using it or uset try/except in your loop.

Comment: Rather than changing the library, perhaps just skip the process with PID=0

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Please could you tell me where I should add this? I am getting lost...

Comment: Well, I don't know for sure whether or not Slava is correct here. But you can check this yourself in `TForm1.FormCreate`. Inside the loop, just after `Process` is assigned, add this: `if Process.ProcessID=0 then continue;`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Thank you, I have done exactly this but I am getting: System Error. Code: 5. Access is denied.

Comment: Yep. Those are the process for which you don't have rights to open the process handle with those rights.

Comment: I think I have it solved - I have removed the RaiseLastOSError checks and now the Full Path is getting added but not for all of the processes.